# Continuous function: Borel and/or Lebesgue measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

If $f\colon [0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function and differentiable on (0,1), then which of the following is correct?

1. $f'$ is Borel and Lebesgue measurable.
2. $f'$ is Borel measurable and is not Lebesgue measurable.
3. $f'$ is not Borel measurable and is not Lebesgue measurable.
4. $f'$ is not Borel measurable and is Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help.

$$f'(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n(f(x + 1/n) - f(x)).$$